# Intune user password provisioning problem

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, intune

We have a non-hybrid scheme and we don't use AD Connect at all. Users change their password in OneLogin and it provisions to Active Directory and Azure AD and then from Azure AD to a users laptop.

On laptops that are only joined to Azure AD & Intune, it works perfectly - password on the laptop updates after a change in OneLogin.

However, we have a bunch of laptops that are joined in the domain as well as in Intune and it seems like domain bind has more priority than the Intune one. If the user tries to change his password without a direct network connection to the domain controller (user is outside of our networks) his laptop user password will not update until he will be in our network again.

So, we are wondering is there any way we can unbind the laptop from the domain without user account deletion, because if we just run this command:`Remove-Computer -ComputerName (Get-Content OldServers.txt) -LocalCredential Domain01\Admin01 -UnJoinDomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -WorkgroupName "Legacy" -Force -Restart` it will unbind the laptop from the domain, but it also will delete the user account from the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot really unbind it like that because the domain user isn't a local user profile on the machine, you can however use some tools to migrate the domain network user profile to a local profile if that's acceptable, for example https://pcmover-10.laplink.com/ (microsoft partnered with them for this tool) or. https://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html

In addition, domain profiles especially passwords that are cached locally on a machine expire eventually, if you could disconnect the domain without deleting profile eventually you wouldn't be able to log in anyway.